# std, boost or other widespread implementation of a hash table container with implicit keys

Tags: c++, hashtable, containers

If I understand it correctly, both std::map and std::unordered_map store keys explicitely (store pairs of keys / values). Is there some other ready to use container (std, boost or other widespread implementation) which would not store the key, but rather allow deriving the key from the stored value using a function (i.e. to use implicit key?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::set` or `std::unordered_set`, with suitable hash and/or comparison functions for the stored value type.

However, lookup will be done by the stored value type, not the key, so you'll also need a way to fabricate a temporary object from a key.

Comment: Do these allow you to do lookups *only with a key*, instead of needing a full object?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I guess not; perhaps I misunderstood the question. But this could be a sensible approach, as long as you can easily create a temporary object from a key.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes that would be (my understanding) a different question/requirement. Out of the box, you could create a partial object with just enough information for the key generation. Then again in most non extreme cases I would go ahead and store the key anyway (memory is cheap nowadays)

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for [Boost.Intrusive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/intrusive.html). Boost Intrusive containers "hook into" your value types to provide the characteristics of a certain container (e.g. set, list, AVL tree, etc.) directly from the objects.

See [Differences between intrusive and non-intrusive containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/intrusive/intrusive_vs_nontrusive.html#intrusive.intrusive_vs_nontrusive.differences_intrusive_vs_nontrusive) for an overview of the differences between STL containers and Boost Intrusive containers.

Answer (score 0):

All ordered containers in C++ library e.g. `std::set` allow for *less comparison* template trait, pass it as a second template parameter (`my_less` in example below). . If you don't do it, `operator<` will be looked up via ADL and used if found (compilation error if not); it should be appropriate for plenty of cases.

Your own trait or `operator<` can be used to define order according to data stored in a set i.e. without key. No data is copied to perform this comparison, please note it takes const references.

If you don't want to create stack object and prefer to use heap pointers instead, you can obviously store `boost::shared_ptr` in standard ordered container and write your *less comparison* trait accordingly. In this case you may also consider using [boost ptr containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html)

Example:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

struct order_by_AB { int a; int b; int c; 
  order_by_AB(int a, int b, int c) : a(a), b(b), c(c) {}
};

struct my_less
{
  bool operator()(const boost::shared_ptr<order_by_AB>& lh, const boost::shared_ptr<order_by_AB>& rh)
  {
    if (lh->a == rh->a)
      return lh->b < rh->b;
    return lh->a < rh->a;
  }
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const boost::shared_ptr<order_by_AB>& rh)
{
  os << "(" << rh->a << "," << rh->b << "," << rh->c << ")";
  return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::set<boost::shared_ptr<order_by_AB>, my_less> data;
    data.insert(boost::shared_ptr<order_by_AB>(new order_by_AB(0, 1, 2)));
    data.insert(boost::shared_ptr<order_by_AB>(new order_by_AB(2, 3, 2)));
    data.insert(boost::shared_ptr<order_by_AB>(new order_by_AB(0, 3, 2)));
    data.insert(boost::shared_ptr<order_by_AB>(new order_by_AB(2, 1, 2)));
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<boost::shared_ptr<order_by_AB>>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

**Edited** to give example of user-specified functor for comparison.
**Edited** to add `boost::shared_ptr` in a container

Comment: As I mentioned on another answer, the problem with this is that you need a full object to do lookups. You can't do a lookup with just a key, like you can with map.

Comment: I don't understand something. What do you want to derive your key from and who should do this derivation? The above code derives key from value stored. This can be delegated if need be, e.g. to member function of a class stored in container. Do you want to derive key without actually accessing the value? If so, where would the data required to derive key value come form?

Comment: Can you do `data[x]` where `x` is not a full `order_by_AB` object? Because a full object may be difficult to come by sometimes: imagine if the object held a some resource.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `full object` , can you please elaborate?

Comment: @bronekk I want to derive the key from the stored value (or the value being inserted). The derivation should be done by a function I can provide (e.g. via traits). R.M.F. formulated by other concern very well - the full object is quite sizable and its construction non-trivial, therefore it would be nice to be able to search by key only. We have such container implemented internally, but I would like to find some standard replacement for it if possible.

Comment: the functor you can provide via template parameter, I updated example code. Since there is no copy made anywhere, I still don't understand your other concern.